# Issue while creating .ipa

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, provisioning-profile, ipa

I have a app with iCloud functions enabled. App works fine while running in device but while trying to create a .ipa file it fails to create.

[image: Issue that happens while creating .ipa]

I cannot create .ipa file because this issue. Please provide some suggestions on this issue.

Comment: Can you please provide an error/issue log?

Comment: @MayankJain no error log will be generated in this case.

Comment: I don't find any error message on console while trying to create a .ipa

Answer (score 0):

This is a a new issue found in Xcode 6.

Solution:

Xcode menu > Preferences > Accounts > (Select Team if needed) > Details > Click Refresh button

Then try to Export the IPA again.

Answer (score 0):

First, you must have an available Develop Account for iOS, and download the certificate and import it into your Mac Keychain. It would resolve the developer profile missing issue.
Then might you need to create an APP ID for this project on Apple Developer Center with iCloud function on, and create develop/product provisioning profile pair. Then Xcode could fix the issue.

P.S.
Raptor's answer is useful on newly updated Xcode6 as I experienced.

Comment: "com.acinfotech.ReceiptsPlusNewBundle" -> my bundle id. My Product name is "Receipts plus" and my iCloud entitlement file created as "Receipts plus.entitlement". Is that a issue?

Comment: Check the capabilities, if your iCloud setting is ON and without issue. If so, I think it is correct.

Comment: its ON and running in device But creating .ipa fails

Comment: I have doubt. For instance,(iCloud enabled project) my bundle ID is "com.mycomp.checkout" so  my project name as should be "checkout" ??

Comment: Usually so. But I cannot certain if it is not OK when them differ.