# Issue in creating .ipa file

Tags: ios, xcode, icloud, ipa

I have a Provisioning profile enabled iCloud and my bundle id is

> > "com.mycompany.ReceiptsPlusNewBundle"

I created a sample project named "checkout" and made all initial setup for iCloud and added code for retrieving. App works fine with no issue when I run in device. When I try to archive and create a .ipa it failed.

Instead I created a another sample named "ReceiptsPlusNewBundle" (project name same as bundle ID "com.mycompany.ReceiptsPlusNewBundle") and replicated the same project code. Again project runs good in device. Now I could archive and make a .ipa file successfully.

So App ID must need to same as project name i.e (Product Name in Xcode) ? Is this correct ? So that the app can create .ipa ? Because two projects run good in device. Suggestions on this issue Please !

Answer (score 0):

No the product name can be different than the app ID.
Are you sure that the app ID is correct in (Targets -> checkout(your project name) -> info -> Bundle identifier) ?

[image]

Comment: Yes under info->Bundle Id is same as app ID. Running in device but ipa creation fails

Comment: What is the error message ? I will update the answer with a screenshot of the app I've recently submitted to app store. The project name was the same as the bundle name, where the app ID was a totally different one (the old project name)

Comment: Is iCloud enabled in this project ? I have no error logs Coz app is working fine. Problem Archive->ad-hoc finally fails to create ipa. My previous question I posted this what I get error while creating ipa. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26709630/issue-while-creating-ipa/26709685?noredirect=1#comment42011736_26709685

Comment: my bundle ID is not same as my project name ! my bundle ID->com.mycompany.ReceiptsPlusNewBundle my project name -> "checkout"

Comment: My project name and bundle name are the same ,while bundle ID is different. And I don't think that having a project name different than the bundle name would make an issue.

Comment: NO iCloud isn't enabled.

Comment: For iCloud enabled there is a concern project name> bundle ID.